# Background Image from CSS is getting repeated

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains a background image coming from the css.As per my need i have to show this div after `77px;` from the top.So i have added `padding-top:77px;` in my css but the background image is not coming below or after to 77px; instead it is coming from top only and getting repeated.If i am adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` then it is leaving 77px; space down in the Div and again it is coming from top only..

Here is the HTML ..

```
 <div class="header-wrapper">
 //Header Div
 </div>
 <div id="headerbodyimage" class="headerbody-wrapper">
  //Header body Div
  </div>
```

And Here is the css..

```
.header-wrapper {
position:fixed;
background: url("../img/new_images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
z-index: 60001;     
width: 100%;
height: 77px;
}

.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("../img/new_images/banner.jpg");
z-index: 60001; 
padding-top:77px;
width: 960px;
height: 242px;    
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Please help me ..THanks

Comment: try background-position property to set background 77px from top

Comment: if you have to show the div `77px` from the `top` you have to give `margin-top:77px;` or am i understanding the question wrong?

Comment: @monkeyinsight How to set it..?

Comment: Take a minute read some reference material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: @SunilHari I added the same but it is not coming down ..it is taking from top only and top has a header Div So image is coming inside to that header div

Comment: @user3924730:to my understanding what you need is you need the header div to be 77px from the top and you want to set a background image to it.Am i right ?

Comment: @SunilHari Exactly the same ..

Comment: @user3924730:is this what you want:http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/x12e7o4k/

Comment: @SunilHari Yes Sir and I also want this image to be in center with `margin:0 auto;` but as soon as i am addding this into the css it is getting displayed from top in fiddle

Comment: @SunilHari I have updated my post with Div and css and below to this header Div i want my Current Div in the center of the screen ..

Comment: @SunilHari R u helping me Sir..

Comment: put the html and css together.Edit your question and put it correctly:@user3924730

Comment: @SunilHari Am i clear Sir?

Comment: headerbody-wrapper should be centered or its background?and headerbody-wrapper should be 77 px from header wrapper ryt?

Comment: @SunilHari Issue Resolved ..I will update my answer Soon.Thanks Sir..

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-position: 0 77px;`

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other styles affecting to your element with class `headerbody-wrapper`?

Comment: Yes that is all the css that i have referenced in that div..and above to this Div is a header div which has position as fixed like `position:fixed;`

Comment: @user3924730 I can't understand, do you want that header should be centered or bg image of header?

Comment: Please see my updated Post .I have two div one is Header and second is header body.My first Div i.e Header is Fixed in position from the Css amd second Div i.e header body i want to display after 77px down to the header Div in the center of the screen but the header body div is not getting down to 77px from the top..Please see my updated post..

Comment: You just need to give style `padding-top: 77px;` to body tag.

Comment: html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px !important; 
}   This is My body tag css and i have addeed padding-top: 77px; still no use

Comment: Remove `!important` from `padding: 0px;` Try not to use `!important` when you declare styles, especially when you define rest styles.

Comment: <div class="header-wrapper">
 //Header Div
 </div> This Div is also coming down to 77px;

Answer (score 0):

A different approach from other responses, as you're using fixed position for the header wrapper, you could set a padding top for the parent container (body, for example):

```
body {padding-top: 77px}
```

Leaving the headbody wrapper:

```
.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("../img/new_images/banner.jpg");
    z-index: 60001; 
    width: 960px;
    height: 242px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I was about to set up a pastebin sample, but didn't have your real images.

Comment: Both the Divs are coming down to `77px;` and second div is coming unde the firts..

Comment: I think you have to add some coordinates to .header-wrapper, like: {top:0;left:0}

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7th98q7/)

```
.header-wrapper {
position:fixed;
background: url("http://eshbeata.com/images/backgrounds/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
z-index: 60001;     
width: 100%;
height: 77px;
}

.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg");
z-index: 60001; 
padding-top:77px;
width: 960px;
height: 242px;    
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have solved your issue .both the images are coming properly.Now youcan position it using background position property the way you want it.